# the way to get the title of chrome menu

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I use the code below to create Chrome extension menu

```
chrome.contextMenus.create(
{"title": "hello world", "type": "normal", "parentId":addNav, "onclick":addNavOnClick}
);
```

I want to get the value of the menu when i click the menu.
I want to get "hello world" when i click the menu, i read the api of the chrome.contextMenus but i can not find the method to get the title of the menu.

- is there a method to get the title
- can i make it

Answer (score 0):

The menu item's title is not returned when a menu item is clicked, so you'll have to make use of the unique id that is returned. Here's a very simple example of what I mean. An object called "menuItems" associates the id with the title, and can be called later in the onclick callback.

```
var menuItems = {};

function onClickCallback(info, tab) {
  console.log("item " + menuItems[info.menuItemId] + " was clicked");
}

var title = "Test menu item 1";
var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "onclick": onClickCallback});
menuItems[id] = title;

var title = "Test menu item 2";
var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "onclick": onClickCallback});
menuItems[id] = title;
```